# Apex object field for reverse lookup

Tags: apex, soql, custom-object, query

Let's say I have 2 custom objects: `Person` and `Award`. `Award` has a lookup field to `Person` called `Receiver`.

If I query an object of `Award`, I know I can do `Award.Receiver__r` to access fields of the related `Person`. Is it possible to do the reverse - provided I know that a specific `Person` object has an `Award` (i.e. an `Award` exists whose lookup field specifies that person), can I access the fields of that `Award` via a field on `Person` object in Apex and/or SOQL?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. You are looking for a [`Left Outer Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Outer_Join), where the type of query you first reference is a [`Right Outer Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Right_Outer_Join). Your query might look like:

```
SELECT (SELECT Id FROM Awards__r) FROM Person__c
```

---

You can control the value of this **`Child Relationship Name`** in the configuration on the lookup field. Custom lookups append `__r` to the relationship name. When configuring the lookup definition, this option will be on `Step 3` of the configuration wizard.

[image: Sample Lookup Configuration (create)]

You can also change it later by editing the field.

[image: Sample Lookup Configuration (edit)]

---

You can verify the child relationship to use programmatically (where I guessed it might be `Awards__r`) using this snippet in `Execute Anonymous`:

```
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.Person__c.getChildRelationships())
    if (relation.getChildSObject() == Award__c.sObjectType)
        system.debug(relation.getRelationshipName()); // use this output verbatim
```

---

Note that while you can treat this sub-query like a field, it contains a `List<Award__c>` in this instance.

```
Person somePerson = [SELECT (SELECT Id FROM Awards__r) FROM Person__c LIMIT 1];
List<Award__c> awards = somePerson.Awards__r;
// you can also get it dynamically
awards = somePerson.getSObjects('Awards__r');
```